# Is the Standard Model experimentally verified?

Tags: standard-model

Has the [Standard Model of Particle Physics](http://www.enwp.org/Standard_Model_%28mathematical_formulation%29)   been experimentally verified?     Or is it still waiting for experimental verification? OR,

What aspects/predictions   of the Standard Model have been experimentally verified?

If not, what are some possible tests for it?

Comment: Do you mean The Standard Model of Particle Physics, which is verified by decades of experiments? Or some general model of a phenomena, and how one establishes its correctness?

Comment: yes, any public data for verification

Comment: Hi 種瓜得瓜種豆得豆, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! It's not at all clear what your question is asking as it is currently written, so I'm going to have to close this. As Jen said, are you asking about the Standard Model of particle physics, or are you asking about any accepted model? Please [edit] your question to clarify that, and then perhaps it can be reopened.

Comment: i want to apply some data to see the effect of standard model for understanding how it work

Comment: http://arxiv.org/ is probably your best resource for free public scientific articles. Here's a recent article which discusses how our empirical knowledge of the parameters of the SM stand after taking into account the discovery of the Higgs boson last year: http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2716

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the site. I will answer assuming that you come from a non western culture ( your nickname is not readable) and English is not your first language,  and that you are a student.

For a model to become standard it means that it has been evaluated many times against data and has always been verified. For example: the heliocentric model of our solar system.

As far as I know this is the only criterion to call a model "standard", that it has many verifications and has not been falsified by any measurements.

**Edit** in response to the comment by the questioner:

If you are thinking of the standard model of particle physics the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) is a start.

For the [heliocentric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliocentric) there is also information there.

One has to search for the theories and verifications with data for each model.

Comment: Another thing is to show the reason(s) for naming something a model opposed to theory. @ 種瓜得瓜種豆得豆 : "a thing" is one of a lot , "The thing" is the one and only, the most important, the master of things.

Comment: Any public data in web for verification of standard model, i am not a student and just a programmer

Comment: @Georg In the example of the solar system the theory is gravitation, the heliocentric system is an "application" of gravitation, or a "solution" of the theory equations. Quotes because it is much more complicated than a simple solution of a differential equation.

Comment: after googled, find no book about it, what's its equations?

Comment: I suppose you mean the particle physics standard model? The wikipedia article introduces it, click on the blue link in my answer above.